# number of paths between opposite boundaries of a cube

Tags: integer-lattices, eulerian-path, rubiks-cube

There is a calculation of the number of surface paths (with no backtracking allowed) between opposite corners of a Rubik's cube. I am interested in paths on an $L\times L\times L$ cube, where $L$ is the number of edges along the $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$ directions. There are two generalizations of the Rubik's cube problem that I am interested in. I am not hoping for an exact calculation but if there exist attempts or references for this, I would like to look at it.

1. The first generalization is allowing paths through both the surface and bulk of the cubic lattice. So the more general question would be: how many paths exist between the opposite corners of the $L\times L\times L$ cube?
2. The second generalization is to consider paths between opposite boundaries and not just opposite corners of the cube. In other words, can the calculation be generalized to the number of paths between two opposite boundaries of a cube? More generally, one could consider a cuboid with dimensions $L_x\times L_y \times L_z$

Are there analytical expressions known for these number of paths? Is there a reference?

Some clarifications based on discussion in the comments: you are allowed to travel every edge only once but you can revisit the nodes.

Comment: The graph of the surface of a cube has more than 2 vertices of odd degree (the 8 corners have 3 edges) so it is not possible to have any [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), i.e. a path that traverses every edge exactly once. I guess there must be some misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit now after your comment. My only requirement for the paths was to not have an edge traversed twice but of course not every edge needs to be traversed

Comment: Are you looking for paths or trails, that is to say, can you visit a node more than once? Note: the term "Eulerian path" is a misnomer nowadays since "path" has changed meaning to no longer allow node revisits, while the term "trail" has been coined for cases where node revisits are allowed.

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to visit a node more than once. In your definition, one can always derive a "path" from a "trail" by removing the small loops, right?

Comment: Yes. There are still lots of people who still use path in the older sense where repeated nodes are allowed, it's not a universal convention, so it is always best to be clear. To be honest I have no idea about answers to your questions, though I doubt there is a formula, and it is sure to grow at least exponentially with L.